# Get most deeply nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested

I have heterogenous nested arrays (each contains a mix of scalars and arrays, which also may contain scalars and arrays, and so on recursively). The goal is to extract all arrays with the maximum depth. Note this does not mean extracting arrays at the "bottom" of any given sub-array (local maximums), but the greatest depth over all sub-arrays.

For example:

```
$testArray= array(
    'test1' => 'SingleValue1',
    'test2' => 'SingleValue2',
    'test3' => array(0,1,2),
    'test4' => array(array(3,4,array(5,6,7)), array(8,9,array(10,11,12)),13,14),
    'test5' => array(15,16,17, array(18,19,20)),
);
```

In this example, the greatest depth any array occurs at is 3, and there are two arrays at that depth:

- `array(5,6,7)`
- `array(10,11,12)`

The code should find these two. (The `[18,19,20]` sub-array is not included, for though it's at the greatest depth in its branch, it's at a lesser depth overall.)

I'm not sure where to start. I've tried many things: using `foreach` in recursive functions, etc., but the end result was always nothing, all elements or the last iterated element. How can this problem be approached? Complete solutions aren't needed, just hints on where to start.

Comment: Post what you've already tried and we can help debug it

Comment: Are you looking for those specific arrays in this specific data set? Or is this a deeper question about being able to extract sub arrays?

Comment: And the array is not static then I guess? How do you know it's 5 6 7, and 10 11 12 you need?

Comment: I know I need these because they're most deeply nested within testArray

Comment: What you can do is set flag for the levels of the mostly deeped nested array which can be intialized to 0. Once it has iterated through it all, the the new value for the flag is the level of the subarray that is most deeply nested. 
You have to run an iteration again, to find the array which subarray(s) is/are at the flag level (the deepest level) and print it out.

Comment: Good question. I can't answer now but I will have a look at this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended solution with [**`RecursiveIteratorIterator`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class:

```
$testArray= array(
    'test1' => 'SingleValue1',
    'test2' => 'SingleValue2',
    'test3' => array(0,1,2),
    'test4' => array(array(3,4,array(5,6,7)), array(8,9,array(10,11,12)),13,14),
    'test5' => array(15,16,17, array(18,19,20)),
);

$it = new \RecursiveArrayIterator($testArray);
$it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
$max_depth = 0;
$items = $deepmost = [];

foreach ($it as $item) {
    $depth = $it->getDepth();        // current subiterator depth
    if ($depth > $max_depth) {       // determining max depth
        $max_depth = $depth;
        $items = [];
    }
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $items[$depth][] = $item;
    }
}

if ($items) {
    $max_key = max(array_keys($items));  // get max key pointing to the max depth
    $deepmost = $items[$max_key];
    unset($items);
}
print_r($deepmost);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 12
        )
)
```

You may wrap this approach into a named function and use it for getting the *deepmost* arrays.

Enjoy! )

Comment: I actually stumble upon the RecursiveIteratorIterator class, but most of it isn't documented. Your code does the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Roman's solution seems to work, but I struggle to read that type of method.  Here's my version of finding the deepest subarrays.

See my inline comments for explanation of each step.  Basically, it checks each array for subarrays, then iterates/recurses when possible, and storea subarrays using the `level` counter as a key.

My custom function will return an array of arrays.

Code: ([Multidimensional Array Demo](https://3v4l.org/7dOru)) ([Flat Array Demo](https://3v4l.org/NIFWr)) ([Empty Array Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZVUnt))

```
function deepestArrays(array $array, int $level = 0, array &$lowest = []): array
{
    $subarrays = array_filter($array, 'is_array');
    if ($subarrays) { // a deeper level exists
        foreach ($subarrays as $subarray) {
            deepestArrays($subarray, $level + 1, $lowest);  // recurse each subarray
        }
    } else {  // deepest level in branch
        $lowestLevel = key($lowest) ?? $level;  // if lowest array is empty, key will be null, fallback to $level value
        if ($lowestLevel === $level) {
            $lowest[$level][] = $array;  // push the array into the results
        } elseif ($lowestLevel < $level) {
            $lowest = [$level => [$array]]; // overwrite with new lowest array
        }
    }
    return current($lowest);  // return the deepest array
}

var_export(
    deepestArrays($testArray)
);
```